# How to make an Open In.. button (iOS)

Tags: ios, ipad, ibooks

I'm new to iOS develpment and want to add to my app an open in.. button so you can view the pdf files the app contains in iBooks or some other app.

How can I add the open in.. button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

For example:

```
[[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileUrl] presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:barButton animated:YES];
```